# Too many command-line arguments when calling pg_dump from java

Tags: java, postgresql, pg-dump

After running into an issue on executing some queries as strings in Java for postgres, I went using string arrays, which solved my existing issues.

After the switch I am now having an issue with `pg_dump`, but not with `pg_restore`.

When I supply my method with the following array:

```
[time, ./pg_dump, -U, lehigh, -d, lehigh, -Fc, data/completedDb.dump]
```

I get the following error:

> pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is
>   "data/completedDb.dump")

ProcessBuilder produces the following for my execution:

```
time ./pg_dump -U lehigh -d lehigh -Fc data/completedDb.dump
```

And it works fine when I add the output arrow, and remove the data folder, on the command line.

```
time ./pg_dump -U lehigh -d lehigh -Fc > completedDb.dump
```

I'm running this through eclipse, in Java on a postgres database, using :

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec();
```

I've tried using `Process.start()` but got the same errors, so I'm totally dumbfounded at what I'm doing wrong.

Prior to this change, `pg_dump` was being executed properly as a single string. I don't want to go back to that method as I want to maintain consistency, but I also want to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use -f before the output file name, since by default pg_dump outputs to stdout.

Try

[time, ./pg_dump, -U, lehigh, -d, lehigh, -Fc, -f, data/completedDb.dump]

Comment: Yup, that's what I was missing.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!  I was having the same problem calling from golang!  2 hours spent tracking this down.  changing ">" to "-f" did it for me!!!!!