# pg_dump too many arguments inside ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, postgresql, psql, processbuilder, pg-dump

We are trying to import a database dump to our local database by pipeing the pg_dump output into psql. It works fine when we execute the command in the command-line, but it fails inside the `ProcessBuilder` of Java

This is how it looks like:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("pg_dump", "-h" + hostRemote, 
"-p" + portRemote, "-U" + usernameRemote, "-a", dbNameRemote, "|",
"psql", "-h" + hostLocal, "-p" + portLocal, "-U" + usernameLocal, dbNameLocal);
```

And this is the error we are getting: pg_dump: too many command line arguments (the first one is |).

Is there some special catch we are not seeing? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Cleaned up separate tokens:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("pg_dump", "-h", hostRemote, 
"-p", Integer.toString(portRemote), "-U", usernameRemote, "-a", dbNameRemote, "|",
"psql", "-h", hostLocal, "-p", Integer.toString(portLocal), 
"-U", usernameLocal, dbNameLocal);
```

Comment: You need to build your array or List and have each token be its own item in the list or array.

Comment: e.g., you're concatenating Strings with whitespace and feeding that in as a token -- don't do that -- instead separate them out as separate tokens with no whitespace in your String tokens. So not `"-h" + hostRemote,` but rather: `"-h", hostRemote,`

Comment: Also, are you capturing streams appropriately?

Comment: Like this?
`("pg_dump", "-h", hostRemote, "-p", Integer.toString(portRemote), "-U", usernameRemote,
                "-a", dbNameRemote, "|",
                "psql", "-h", hostLocal, "-p", Integer.toString(portLocal), "-U", usernameLocal, dbNameLocal)`. Same error sadly.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Same error output, sadly. Thanks so far!

Comment: Did you then check out [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560868/too-many-command-line-arguments-when-calling-pg-dump-from-java)? Perhaps you're calling your commands incorrectly for use in a Java Process.

Comment: Yes. Even the minimal example provided here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html does yield the same error: `new ProcessBuilder("pg_dump", "-h", hostRemote, dbNameRemote, "|",
                "psql", "-h", hostLocal , dbNameLocal);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @Hovercraft Full Of Eels pushed me into the right direction.
`ProcessBuilder` does not support pipeing out of the box. We either need to spawn a shell with the `ProcessBuilder` and then feed the command into the shell or create two separate processes and then redirect the output of the pg_dump to the input of the psql! We chose the latter one.